# backup da estrutura dos databases do sql

Tags: sql-server

Bom dia, tenho vários servidores que~utilizo no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento, porém gostaria de saber se os colegas conhecem alguma ferramenta ou procedimento no próprio sql que eu consiga fazer um backup somente da estrutura dos databases.

Ou seja, se ocorrer um desastre nesse ambiente, não preciso voltar os dados pois como se trata de um ambiente de desenvolvimento, só a estrutura é o suficiente.

Dessa forma eu também ocuparia bem menos espaço para reter os backups que faço.

Desde já muito obrigado.

Comment: no sql manager você consegue gerar um script para criar os esquemas, tabelas, procedures, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JeanBraz, caso utilize o SQL Server Management Studio, você pode gerar um Script com a estrutura do Banco de Dados.

`DataBase` > `Right Click` > `Tarefas` > `Gerar Scripts` > `...Todo o Banco de Dados...` > `Avançado` > `Tipos de dados dos quais gerar script` > `Esquema somente` > `OK`

Agora você precisa escolher onde salvar o script, o resto é apenas o bom e velho Next > Next > Finish.

**EDIT**

Abaixo segue um exemplo de SMO:
No Visual Studio, inclua na sua solução uma `Console Application`
Então importe as seguintes DLLs do Sql Server Management Studio:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll

Caso tenha o Sql Management Studio 2012 na sua maquina, você poderá encontrar estas DLLs no seguinte endereço fisico:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies
```

Por fim, substitua o seu Program.cs pelo seguinte:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MyProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write(Program.CreateScript());
        }

        private static string CreateScript()
        {
            var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server ConnectionString");
            var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
            var server = new Server(serverConnection);
            var database = server.Databases["DataBase Name"];

            var scripter = new Scripter(server);
            scripter.Options.ScriptDrops = false;
            scripter.Options.WithDependencies = true;
            scripter.Options.Indexes = true;
            scripter.Options.DriAllConstraints = true;
            scripter.Options.Triggers = true;
            scripter.Options.FullTextIndexes = true;
            scripter.Options.NoCollation = false;
            scripter.Options.Bindings = true;
            scripter.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = false;
            scripter.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = true;
            scripter.Options.ExtendedProperties = true;
            scripter.PrefetchObjects = true;

            var listaUrn = new List<Urn>();
            foreach (Table table in database.Tables)
                if (!table.IsSystemObject)
                    listaUrn.Add(table.Urn);

            foreach (View view in database.Views)
                if (view.IsSystemObject == false)
                    listaUrn.Add(view.Urn);

            foreach (StoredProcedure storedProcedure in database.StoredProcedures)
                if (storedProcedure.IsSystemObject == false)
                    listaUrn.Add(storedProcedure.Urn);

            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var stringCollection = scripter.Script(listaUrn.ToArray());
            foreach (var script in stringCollection)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(script);
                stringBuilder.AppendLine("GO");
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

No mais você só precisa adaptar o programar para salvar o Script em um arquivo.

Comment: Prezado, sabe se tenho como automatizar essa tarefa, pois tenho vários bancos e esse processo precisa ser diário uma vez que a estrutura pode mudar e para fazer o processo manual é inviável.

Comment: Você pode fazer isto utilizando SMO (Server Management Objects) para gerar os Scripts e Jobs para agendar a execução diariamente.